# Which standalone head units would work with Tacx i.Flow T2270?

Tags: compatibility, turbo-trainer

I'd like to be able to use my [Tacx i.Flow T2270](http://www.tacx.com/products/trainers/i-flow) trainer without a PC.

Apart from the [T2202](http://activesport.co.uk/shop/article_T2202/T2202-Tacx-Head-Unit-Flow-%282012%3E%29-White_Blue.html), which current or older standalone head units would be compatible? Would [T1682](http://activesport.co.uk/shop/article_T1682/T1682-Tacx-Head-Unit-Flow.html) work? What about head units from other Tacx models?

(I am looking to buy secondhand, so would like to understand my options.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tacx i-Flow is only compatible with the T2202 head unit for standalone use.

The T1982 Bushido head unit does not connect in my experience, although I have had Tacx support tell me it should work.

The T1962 Flow head unit firmware is not compatible withe I-Flow.

Your best guaranteed option is the T2022.